# Specifying a base or default font with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, file-conversion

Is there a system property or other parameter that can be passed to PDFBox when attempting to convert from a PDF document into an Image? I am utilizing the provided PDF2Image class like so:

```
String[] args = new String[]{"-imageType", "jpg", "myfile.pdf"};
org.apache.pdfbox.PDFToImage.main(args);
```

It works great on Windows and fails with this warning on Ubuntu:

```
[org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine] java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.getawtFont(PDType1Font.java:261)
```

I assume from my research that this is a problem with a "missing" font, but I've found very little help so far using google and the projects website.

I've tried both versions 1.7.1 and 1.8.2 of PDFBox.

Similar question here: [setting ttf for PDF to Image on PDFbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665300/setting-ttf-for-pdf-to-image-on-pdfbox)