# PDFBox Embeded fonts not working when filling form

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, pdfbox

I fill forms with **field.setValue**. However even though PDF document has embedded fonts in it, I am getting error **"is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding"** no matter which type of font it is. Note that this is happening for chinese or russian characters.

Comment: Do you probably try to set values containing characters outside the Latin-15 range?

Answer (score 2):

Your PDF documents may have embedded fonts but they apparently have been embedded with an **Encoding** value **WinAnsiEncoding**.

**WinAnsiEncoding** contains essentially the Latin-15 characters, so it is *intended for “Western European” languages* (see the [Wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)) and in particular neither for Cyrillic nor for CJK languages.

If you want to fill *chinese or russian characters* into form fields using PDFBox, therefore, you have to

- either embed a font into your PDF using an appropriate encoding beforehand
- or replace the embedded font with PDFBox right before setting the form field value, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57456816/1729265).